# JWT Authentication with Spring boot Withot using userDetail

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am implementing  rest APIs  for mobile App and want to use JWT token in that. I Have achieved this by implmenting it with userDetials object.
Now my problem is I don't have a Users table in the database I just have a phone number and UUID.
We can achieve this by changing the signature to use the phone number as a signature .
But my question is how I will authenticate each request?
And How I can validate the token using my own object which does not contains username and password.
AS per my implementation I will have to se spring security and when I will use spring security. Spring Security will require UserDetail Service which will give me back spring User object.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this by implementing user details
here is an example for authentication by username and domain

```
public class SimpleUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    // ...

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String usernameAndDomain = StringUtils.split(
          username, String.valueOf(Character.LINE_SEPARATOR));//split as much as you want
        if (usernameAndDomain == null || usernameAndDomain.length != 2) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username and domain must be provided");
        }
        User user = userRepository.findUser(usernameAndDomain[0], usernameAndDomain[1]);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
              String.format("Username not found for domain, username=%s, domain=%s", 
                usernameAndDomain[0], usernameAndDomain[1]));
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Karim,
I don't have user object at all.       
User user = userRepository.findUser(usernameAndDomain[0], usernameAndDomain[1]);
How this line gonna work ?

Comment: that's just an example user could be any object that implements this interface
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html

Comment: You can create a custom userdetails class implementing org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails interface. Pass your class [containing the phone number and UUID] to the constructor of your custom userdetails class. Override getUsername() and getPassword() methods returning both your phone number and UUID respectively. SimpleUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername() method should return your custom userdetails class.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66255654/jwt-authentication-with-spring-boot-withot-using-userdetail#comment117138797_66256073), you should create a custom user details service. The loadUserByUsername() method of your SimpleUserDetailsService class should return your custom user details.

Entity

```
public class Pojo {
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String uuid;

    // Getters Setters Constructors
}
```

Custom User Details

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public CustomUserDetails(Pojo pojo) {
        this.username = pojo.getPhoneNumber();
        this.password = pojo.getUuid();

        authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorityList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
      return true;
    }

}
```

User details service impl